# Replace values between two dataframes

Tags: r

I have dataframe (df) as below. This is the output of merging two DF's per hour. The NA's are those hours the data did not arrive into system at that hour.

```
Vol     Nu        Date       lat      long
0       NA  2017-01-01 01     NA       NA
2       NA  2017-01-01 02     NA       NA
0       NA  2017-01-01 03     NA       NA
0       NA  2017-01-01 07     NA       NA
0       NA  2017-01-01 08     NA       NA
0        2  2017-01-01 09  80.85243 26.78307
0       NA  2017-01-01 10     NA       NA
0       NA  2017-01-01 11     NA       NA
0        2  2017-01-02 01  80.90426 26.77535
2       NA  2017-01-02 02    NA       NA
3       NA  2017-01-02 03     NA       NA
0       NA  2017-01-02 04     NA       NA
0       NA  2017-01-02 05     NA       NA
0        2  2017-01-02 06  80.90426 26.77535
.
.
.
.
```

All I need to get the output as below, where depending on a particular day, I have to clone the data in any of the hour. Ex on 2017-01-01 09 hour, I have data, so I will expand it to rest of the hours of the same data and so on with other date 2017-01-02...

**Expected Output**

```
Vol     Nu        Date       lat      long
0        2  2017-01-01 01  80.85243 26.78307
2        2  2017-01-01 02  80.85243 26.78307
0        2  2017-01-01 03  80.85243 26.78307
0        2  2017-01-01 07  80.85243 26.78307
0        2  2017-01-01 08  80.85243 26.78307
0        2  2017-01-01 09  80.85243 26.78307
0        2  2017-01-01 10  80.85243 26.78307
0        2  2017-01-01 11  80.85243 26.78307
0        2  2017-01-02 01  80.90426 26.77535
2        1  2017-01-02 02  80.90426 26.77535
3        1  2017-01-02 03  80.90426 26.77535
0        1  2017-01-02 04  80.90426 26.77535
0        1  2017-01-02 05  80.90426 26.77535
0        1  2017-01-02 06  80.90426 26.77535
```

It would be very helpful if you can help me.

Note: the data set is pretty big... more than a million rows populated per day. I just showed few records above.

Comment: What if you have data in more than one row in a day? Which one will you select?

Comment: hi Ronak Shah... any one would be fine.. since they become unique by row id and cluster number at the end which i did not mention here... just not to over provide the details.. but any  one row would be fine.. as they will be same

Comment: Check if the marked duplicate solves your problem. You might have to tweak your data to use it.

Comment: @Ronak, actually it does not.. it talks ablout just one vector..i have around 50 variables that needs to be duplicated.. i cann't go one by one..